# What is the mathematics behind the architecture of AlexNet?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I've been trying to learn more about convolutional neural networks (coming from an SVM background) and I've been struggling with understanding how decisions were made when designing some of the leading architectures like VGG's, ResNet, and the like. Decisions like dropout rates, the depth of the network, the sizes of the kernels, strides, using overlapping pooling, etc. I know this is a loaded question, so maybe we can restrict this to the fire-starter: [AlexNet](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/4824-imagenet-classification-with-deep-convolutional-neural-networks.pdf). Section 3.4 of the linked paper gives the following reason for using overlapping pooling:

*"We generally observe during training that models with overlapping
pooling find it slightly more difficult to overfit."*

Is there some mathematical justification for this, or is it just throw-stuff-at-the-wall-and-see-what-sticks? I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: My impression is that this is largely a matter of trial and error, guided maybe by some vague intuition. I've never heard of any deep, principled way to understand why some architectures seem to work better than others for certain tasks. Good question, though.

Comment: Don't expect cogent mathematical justifications behind deep learning architectures. It's mostly empirical.

Comment: Araújo, D., Oliveira, R. I., & Yukimura, D. (2019). A mean-field limit for certain deep neural networks. arXiv preprint arXiv:1906.00193.

Comment: Thanks guys, this was about what I was expecting. I guess I was hoping for something more structured in the design of CNNs, but oh well! It makes me nervous while I read about them because I feel like I’m memorizing rather than understanding (if that makes sense). Thanks again!